# Excel vsto addin cannot find dependent dlls when installed with clickonce

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

I have a VSTO Excel addin which is working fine when launched from the visual studio debugger - it installs and all buttons work without any problems. But if I try to install it either by publishing it or double clicking the .vsto file, then it installs and works ok for any operation that does not reference other dlls. For such button clicks there is no visible effect in Excel. For other button clicks where the behaviour was directly coded in the addin assembly without reference to any other dlls the result is fine. So for some reason the clickonce installer is not copying the dlls to the right place, and fails to access them at runtime. Any suggestions on why the dlls are not getting hooked up properly?

Comment: Has it ever worked when published? Do you have a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Actually I have found that it is the dlls from a particular nuget package that are not being copied by the click-once (I tested by adding other dummy dlls and they are copied and execute at runtime in the addin). Any thoughts on properties of some dlls that prevent them from being copied?

Comment: Can't say that I have any ideas; I have at least one NuGet package in mine and it works as expected (DocumentFormat.OpenXmlSDK 2.0.0). At least you've narrowed it down some.